# I have no clue why this isnt working. Seems like a simple script but I keep getting 0 as my result which I know is incorrect

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement, while-loop

```
rows = len(myarray[0,:])
columns = len(myarray[:,1])
number_of_coordinates = 0
i=0
j=0
while i < rows:
    while j < columns:
        if int(myarray[i][j]) == 1:
            print("Found one!")
            number_of_coordinates += 1
        j += 1
    i += 1
print(number_of_coordinates)
```

Should print out a high number I know I have many 1s in this array and the integers 2-10.
The type of "int(myarray[i][j])" is "int" so I do not know what is wrong.

Comment: That's not C.  What language is it?

Comment: Yah sorry its python. I keep switching from python to C and I am new to both so I get confused a lot

Comment: Why are you using `while` loops here?  `for` loops are vastly more appropriate when looping over a known numeric range - and would have avoided the problem of failing to reinitialize one of your variables.  Why are you using loops *at all*, given that you're apparently using `numpy` arrays?  The whole POINT of `numpy` is that it can efficiently perform operations on entire arrays.  Your count of 1s could be written as `np.count_nonzero(myarray == 1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't reinitialize `j` to zero,

```py
rows = len(myarray[0,:])
columns = len(myarray[:,1])
number_of_coordinates = 0
i=0
j=0
while i < rows:
    
    while j < columns:
        if int(myarray[i][j]) == 1:
            print("Found one!")
            number_of_coordinates += 1
        j += 1
    i += 1
    j = 0 # Look at it
print(number_of_coordinates)
```

Assuming you are using Python.